# Swift3 Indexed UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

I know this type of thing has been asked before but any answers I find are either out of date or in Objective C so I think it's worth asking again
 Writing an app in which I want to show a indexed tableview of contact information.

I've got have an array of NSObject, with properties for code, name, phone and email.
In my viewDidLoad function, I'm loading this array up from a web service no problem and able to display it in the tableview fine.
However dealing with 200+ rows is a little cumbersome so want to add in indexes and sections
All the examples I found seem to deal with an array of strings, no one seems to touch on and array of NSObjects.  I've tried adapting the example I found at http://nshipster.com/uilocalizedindexedcollation/ but again seems out of date so haven't succeed.

Any help please

Comment: You need to generate the index from your objects first.

Comment: Actually, I think you might of just really made think I might of asked the wrong question.  building the index is probably my problem.  How would I best go about building the index?

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to be researching the same thing. Try this demo (no. 36) https://github.com/PrashantMangukiya/SwiftUIDemo by Prashant Mangukiya

Works for me.